# Get WiFi router information in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, terminal

What Linux terminal commands can help me gather information about all WiFi routers my laptop can detect?

I mean things like name, channel, encryption type etc.

(Linux, Debian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`iwlist`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwlist8.html). Ordinarily you would do something like `iwlist wlan0 scan`

(Where wlan0 is the name of your wireless network interface.)